# Android Installation Issue - Ignoring unknown package filter 'platform-tools'

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, installation

I've been at this for a while now, and I've lost quite a bit of work time due to this error. I am just trying to install a fresh copy of Android Studio on my Mac running El Captian. Every single time it tries to install the SDK, I get this:

```
Ignoring unknown package filter 'platform-tools'
```

And it will not allow me to do anything. I have tried completely uninstalling android, installing fresh, restarting, and so on, but with absolutely no luck whatsoever. I've tried using a separate download with just the SDK tools, but same result. Was hoping someone could offer a solution that may have run across this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even i started facing this problem today. I followed the below steps post which it started working fine.

After installing android sdk, navigate to /Users/<>/Library/Android/sdk/tools and then run the below command.

```
./android update sdk -u
```

Accept the licences by entering y. This will download the platform tools and other sdk's.

After this go to Applications and open android studio. 
It should now be working fine.

Comment: `./android update sdk -u `

Just install all packages from "Tools" and "Extras". Additionally you could install SDK Platform to a couple of the newest Android versions. Restart Android SDK Manager and Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I installed it manually.

$ cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools

$ ./android list sdk

Output:

```
... 
Packages available for installation or update: 48
1- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.1
2- Documentation for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
3- SDK Platform Android N Preview, revision 1
4- SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2
5- SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2 
...
```

$ ./android update sdk --no-ui --filter 1